Agora Voice call local audio track heard the voice as twice
Voice call features are integrated into our angular web app. Here problem is local audio track voices are heard twice. We did it for the video call. There haven't problems on the audio and video. Only in the voice call, we can hear our voice twice. Could anyone please share your suggestion on this

this.rtc.localAudioTrack = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack({encoderConfig: "speech_standard",AEC: true, ANS: true});

   this.rtc.localAudioTrack.play("");
   await this.rtc.client.publish([this.rtc.localAudioTrack]);

